# I want to copy files to AWS ec2 using buildspec.yml file, the 22 port is open for all the traffic. How to restrict the 22nd port for only codebuild?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, pipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-pipeline

I want to ssh to the aws ec2 server on port `22`. The port is open for all traffic. I want to restrict the traffic for only **aws codebuild** pipeline. How I can do this?

I want to ssh to the aws ec2 server on port `22`. The port is open for all traffic. I want to restrict the traffic for only **aws codebuild** pipeline. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's advaisable using AWS Systems Manager run command versus scp and ssh commands directly to the instance. Update the CodeBuild project role with the necessary permissions. Store files in a private S3 Bucket. To restrict access leverage IAM or resouse based Policies with conditions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html

Notes:
There is no way to restrict SG ingress rule to allow CodeBuild servise. It just doesn't make sense. Even if you get a pool of IPs used by CodeBuild service it doesn't look like a secure solution.

VPC hosted CodeBuild instance? Maybe... But still not the most secure and as flexible as ssm connection.

VPC Endpoints for CodeBuild? It works another way around.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to use VPC Endpoints for codebuild? 
Thanks